# Printing the nodes of a tree

Tags: c, recursion, printing, tree

I have a k-ary tree represented like that:

```
struct node {
    int num;
    int data;
    struct node **kids;
}
```

I have created a function in order to print the data of the nodes of the tree.

Example:

```
     a
   / | \
  b  c  d
 /
e
```

will print:

```
a
b 
e
c
d
```

The function is:

```
void visit(struct node *head){
    int i;

    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d\n", head->data);

    for (i = 0; i < head->num; i++)
        visit(head->kids[i]);

}
```

Question is, how can I also print the level of each node that i print. I tried to declare a variable int level = 0; and increment it but it won't work because the recursive call resets it.

Comment: just pass `level + 1` as a parameter to recursive call

Comment: Shouldn't your current function `visit` print your example tree as `a b e c d` instead of `a b c d e`?

Comment: btw your function does traversing by depth, not by width so the output will not be as shown.

Comment: Is it possible to edit my function and traverse by width?

Answer (score 1):

> void visit(struct node *head){
>       static int i;

```
if (head == NULL)
    return;

printf("%d\n", head->data);
printf("Level : %d\n",i);
for (i = 0; i < head->num; i++)
    visit(head->kids[i]);
i = i + 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pass another parameter to recursive function

```
void visit(struct node *head, int level){
    int i;

    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d : %d\n",level, head->data);

    for (i = 0; i < head->num; i++)
        visit(head->kids[i], level + 1);

}
```

And first time, invoke the function by passing level as zero.